# Factoring with 5 terms

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm doing some factoring and have arrived at the point where the book says that:

$$(k+1)/30(6k^4 + 39k^3 + 91k^2 + 89k + 30)$$

factors to:

$$(k+1)/30(k+2)(2k+3)(3(k+1)^2+3(k+1)-1)$$

I cannot derive the latter using the former. Can someone help? This must be a tough cookie to crack because even my solutions manual doesn't actually do the factoring, it just assumes it by 'knowing what we expected the simplified expression to be'. I'd like to know how to do it on my own, seeing how a lot of the advanced courses involve heavy-duty factoring. Thanks.

Comment: The second has a variable $n$ that the first does not.  What is it?  They will not be equal except for specific values of $n$

Comment: Sorry they should all be k's. I added what I'd already factored out as well, which was a factor of k+1/30

Comment: Please be careful with parentheses with the division slash.  In this case, the question does not depend on whether everything except the $(k+1)/30$ is in the denominator or the numerator, but often it does.  We see both assumptions in questions-usually one can guess, but not always.

Comment: Good point, it's a bit ambiguous. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a good application of the [rational roots theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).  $-2$ and $-\frac 23$ would be in the list of possibilities.  What is left is $3k^2+9k+5$.  Finding the expression with $(k+1)$ would be a bit of inspection or inspiration

Comment: Thanks. I guess I really just wanted to be sure there wasn't a straightforward way to derive it that I was missing. It doesn't appear that there is but I'll read up on the rational roots theorem.

Comment: It says all rational roots of a polynomial with integer coefficients have a numerator that is a factor of the constant term (here 30) and a denominator that is a factor of the coefficient of the leading term (here 6), including a possible minus sign.  Here you would have $64$ choices to try, a bunch but not too big.  When you find one, you can divide it out and reduce the search space.

Answer (score 0):

To factor:

$$f(k)=6k^4 + 39k^3 + 91k^2 + 89k + 30$$

Assuming we didn't know any factors already, try some specific values (noting that all positive values of $k$ will not produce solutions):

$k\ :\ f(k)$

```
0  30
-1 -1
-2 0
```

So we have found $f(-2)=0$, which means that $k+2\text{ divides }f(k).$  It appears there is another solution $k\in (-1,0)$, but that would not be as easy to find.  Of course, once $k+2$ has been divided out we have a cubic, and the solution(s) may not be nice but they are findable.  If you already know a solution is in a given interval, and you suspect it may be a "nice" number, you can divide the interval in half repeatedly until you have a good approximation of the value of the solution and you can guess at the "nice" form it may have.